# Flutter ios build error after adding one signal target

Tags: ios, flutter, onesignal

App Store Connect Operation Error
CFBundleIdentifier Collision. There is more than one bundle with the CFBundleIdentifier value 'com.Example' under the iOS application 'Runner.app'.

App Store Connect Operation Error Bad bundle identifier. The bundle identifier 'com.Example' of the application extension Runner.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex should start with the application's bundle identifier 'com.Example' and not contain more than one period “.” after the application's bundle ID.

after adding onesignal tagert problem occured. please help thanks.

Comment: I have the same case like yours, did u find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

In the runner section in Xcode, in targets change OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension bundle identifer to add a ".extension name" (which is onesignal). The issue is because the bundle indentifier and the extension identifer bundle ID is the same which leads to a collision.

Comment: I rename bundle identifier into: com.example.projectname.OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.onesignal and still can not build an apk in ios, should I add another configuration in xcode ?